# How to load last 7 days into a string(list)

Tags: mysql, sql-date-functions, mysql-date

I'm trying to create a program that watches and searches for any logs within given dates.

How can I load the last 7 days in `DATE` format (YYYY-MM-DD) to a string/string list, or via SQL, or Qt/C++.

Currently, I have this SQL command:

```sql
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL -7 DAY
```

Which displays (for today, "24. 1. 2024") only one value: "2024-01-17".

What I'd like to get is this:

> 2024-01-24 \n 2024-01-23
>
> 2024-01-22
>
> 2024-01-21
>
> 2024-01-20
>
> 2024-01-19
>
> 2024-01-18
>
> 2024-01-17

I know for sure that I've basically told SQL to "pick a date from now seven days back", so it's wrong as it is, but need to edit it so it'll display 7 different date values for each day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive cte to get the result you want:

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_ranges AS (
   SELECT CURDATE() as d
   UNION ALL
   SELECT d - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   FROM date_ranges
   WHERE d > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
SELECT * FROM date_ranges;
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/_pi2a0eZ)

Answer (score 0):

See example. Generate series from date for MySql

```
select date_sub(cast('2024-01-17' as date), interval d day) dt,d
from (values row(0),row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), row(7)
  ) t(d)
```

| dt | d |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-17 | 0 |
| 2024-01-16 | 1 |
| 2024-01-15 | 2 |
| 2024-01-14 | 3 |
| 2024-01-13 | 4 |
| 2024-01-12 | 5 |
| 2024-01-11 | 6 |
| 2024-01-10 | 7 |